# About SharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

i was just wondering, if i wanted to reset the actual preference file used with SharedPreferences could i just rename the preference file ? , wouldn't that mean that the file
still exist or does overwrite it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
prefs.edit().clear().commit(); // prefs = SharedPreferences
```

is the proper way. Deleting the file with no referencing `SharedPreferences` objects should result the same.